# Is there a simple way to keep a constantly updating file pushed to a git repo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, version-control

I have a git repo including a program that uses a data file for input. Separately to development, web data is being scraped and saved to the file on one machine. I want to, essentially, have access to the latest version of this file on git across multiple devices.

Is there a simple way to do this using git, or should I look at storing the file elsewhere (like Google Drive) and pointing the program to that file?

(bonus points for a one-line Python solution)

Comment: Definitely elsewhere.

Comment: If on the development machine you can schedule periodic git commits and pushes up to the remote ***bare*** repository (*crontab*, e.g.), then a post-receive hook on the remote repository can install the commit into the work directory. This is predicated on two if's.

Answer (score 0):

You may need [crontab](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/crontab-in-linux-with-examples/) to update the workspace periodically.

example (every 5 minutes):

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh ~/update.sh
```

in the `update.sh`:

```
cd somewhere
git pull
```